# 'System.Int32' does not contain a property with the name 'HasValue'

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding, visual-studio-2013, objectdatasource

I am trying to do a simple program to try ObjectDataSource but in the browser the form is constantly throwing exceptions.

This is my code->

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ODSD;

namespace ODSD.App_Code.Biz
{
   public class Bal
   {
      public List<int?> GetTerritories()
      {
          try 
          {
              using (var context = new ODSD.App_Code.Data.NorthWindDataContext())
              {            
                   var ter = (from c in context.Customers
                              select c.TerritoryID).Distinct();
                   return ter.ToList();
              }
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {     
               throw;
          } 
      }
   }
}
```

Since it is giving error with DataBinding I checked the NorthWind.dbml code but it seems to be fine.

This is my webconfig file -.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>        
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web> 
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
           <assemblies>
              <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
           </assemblies> 
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Maybe the version or httpruntime is the problem?
Because in the visual studio it is showing the proper members etc. but in the browser it is parsing 'c' to int32... (Judging by the initial exception that System.Int32 doesn't have a member called TerritoryID' )

I have searched a lot but the context for the databinding errors seems to be a lot different (and advanced than this one.)

EDIT:

NorthWind.dbml.layout->

NorthWind.designer.cs

```
#pragma warning disable 1591


namespace ODSD.App_Code.Data
{
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System;


[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="AdventureWorks2012_Data")]
public partial class NorthWindDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{

    private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnCreated();
partial void InsertCustomer(Customer instance);
partial void UpdateCustomer(Customer instance);
partial void DeleteCustomer(Customer instance);
#endregion

    public NorthWindDataContext() : 
            base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks2012_DataConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public NorthWindDataContext(string connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public NorthWindDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public NorthWindDataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public NorthWindDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Customer>();
        }
    }
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="Sales.Customer")]
public partial class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _CustomerID;

    private System.Nullable<int> _PersonID;

    private System.Nullable<int> _StoreID;

    private System.Nullable<int> _TerritoryID;

    private string _AccountNumber;

    private System.Guid _rowguid;

    private System.DateTime _ModifiedDate;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnCustomerIDChanging(int value);
partial void OnCustomerIDChanged();
partial void OnPersonIDChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnPersonIDChanged();
partial void OnStoreIDChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnStoreIDChanged();
partial void OnTerritoryIDChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnTerritoryIDChanged();
partial void OnAccountNumberChanging(string value);
partial void OnAccountNumberChanged();
partial void OnrowguidChanging(System.Guid value);
partial void OnrowguidChanged();
partial void OnModifiedDateChanging(System.DateTime value);
partial void OnModifiedDateChanged();
#endregion

    public Customer()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_CustomerID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int CustomerID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CustomerID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._CustomerID != value))
            {
                this.OnCustomerIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._CustomerID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("CustomerID");
                this.OnCustomerIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_PersonID", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> PersonID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._PersonID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._PersonID != value))
            {
                this.OnPersonIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._PersonID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("PersonID");
                this.OnPersonIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_StoreID", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> StoreID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._StoreID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._StoreID != value))
            {
                this.OnStoreIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._StoreID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("StoreID");
                this.OnStoreIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_TerritoryID", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> TerritoryID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._TerritoryID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._TerritoryID != value))
            {
                this.OnTerritoryIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._TerritoryID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("TerritoryID");
                this.OnTerritoryIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_AccountNumber", AutoSync=AutoSync.Always, DbType="VarChar(10) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false, IsDbGenerated=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string AccountNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this._AccountNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._AccountNumber != value))
            {
                this.OnAccountNumberChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._AccountNumber = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("AccountNumber");
                this.OnAccountNumberChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_rowguid", DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL")]
    public System.Guid rowguid
    {
        get
        {
            return this._rowguid;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._rowguid != value))
            {
                this.OnrowguidChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._rowguid = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("rowguid");
                this.OnrowguidChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ModifiedDate", DbType="DateTime NOT NULL")]
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ModifiedDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ModifiedDate != value))
            {
                this.OnModifiedDateChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ModifiedDate = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ModifiedDate");
                this.OnModifiedDateChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

http://s1244.photobucket.com/user/Aearombereth/media/Capture.png.html

EDIT : COMPLETE ERROR MESSAGE

```
DataBinding: 'System.Int32' does not contain a property with the name 'HasValue'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Int32' does not contain a property with the name 'HasValue'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Int32' does not contain a property with the name 'HasValue'.]
   System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName) +9805821
   System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName, String format) +8
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable dataSource) +9754705
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +23
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446
```

Using as a DataSource to a DropDownList

http://s1244.photobucket.com/user/Aearombereth/media/Capture2.png.html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Demo1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ODSD.Demo1" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

</div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="TerritoryDD" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"  DataValueField="HasValue" DataTextField="HasValue" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetTerritories" TypeName="ODSD.App_Code.Biz.Bal" ></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <asp:GridView ID="Customers" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="CustomerDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" Height="50px" Width="125px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us the WHOLE code. Not just a sample. According to the diagram for Northwind, the Customer table doesn't have any field called TerritoryID. So your query doesn't even make sense. How are we supposed to help you, when all the code you post doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Euphoric I have used the Linq to Sql class tool of Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you post diagram of your database? Because the model you posted doesn't seem like a standard NorthWind db.

Comment: I have just used the name NorthWind... the database is actually adventureworks...

Comment: Can you show a: the **entire and complete** error message along with any inner exceptions and the start of the stack trace, and b: where and how you are using objectdatasource?